# Old blockchain info wallet password lost

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

I have a very very long time not used my blockchain info account (it is from before blockchain info has new version)
and I forgot my password + my second password, but I find this saved data from my wallet on my stick.

The data looks like:

```
{
    "guid": "8d07f7c2-b947-4b3d-80a7-3138dcf3fa80",
    "sharedKey": "eb8bab6b-f00a-4861-83b3-24d7b2938a74",
    "double_encryption": true,
    "dpasswordhash": "76296efc1718b4b57a4ebe0287a35ad4565bf84d4e4437963bd2d06a5b981b1f",
    "options": {
        "pbkdf2_iterations": 10,
        "fee_policy": 0,
        "html5_notifications": false,
        "logout_time": 600000,
        "tx_display": 0,
        "always_keep_local_backup": false,
        "transactions_per_page": 30,
        "additional_seeds": []
    },
    "keys": [
        {
            "created_device_name": "javascript_web",
            "addr": "132uY8ULMT6efFdqWjQ74BfaMt46MgpW2F",
            "priv": "mFmbijM0I7Vn7lOv3XcaayhjxXu0qkhd3gNapgknJdudpQn8H9zZw/uOZ/zZ2HDFDkgQV4n1ZX8VjX12qCymDw==",
            "created_device_version": "1.0",
            "created_time": 0
        },
        {
            "created_device_name": "merchant_api",
            "addr": "1AdbcgN8jFYqErMLiUfhFwSJ2jAa3qYCpv",
            "priv": "PG8w31iFpUiWdTjybhy3fK8Lb/VGqVChZxD0S7U4PgGsyLJbUKFNkipC8PMeD7oUt4HYHqmPzvWspHMyO/jSHQ==",
            "created_device_version": "1.0"
        }
    ]
};
```

Its someone used blockchain info in last year was a export option for key - and that I will recompensate all professional help and working idea how to import this data in any type of new wallet to I can have access the coins.

Comment: Without the passwords, I believe your coins are 100% gone.   You must try to remember your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way the blockchain.info wallet works, without the password (and the second password if enabled), there's no way for you to recover your funds.

As a last resort, if you remember bits of the password, you can try to use services/software that'll try to bruteforce the wallet ; given the low balance of your addresses, I doubt it's worth it.

Sorry for your loss.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the part that reads:

`"addr":"132uY8ULMT6efFdqWjQ74BfaMt46MgpW2F"`

is your Address.

From [**this link**](https://blockchain.info/address/132uY8ULMT6efFdqWjQ74BfaMt46MgpW2F), it appears that is a valid address, which has a current balance of less than $20.

Unless you can remember your address, your money is probably gone.